# Web API Dependency Injection with Unity error - System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container, dependency-resolver

I am trying to implement the dependency injection in ASP.Net web API with unity container and have implemented the exactly with below 2 articles:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38770689/3698716
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

Both are related to each other with some minor change but implementation for both are same.

After implementing my code is breaking at `return _container.Resolve(serviceType);` with stackoverflow exception in the GetService method of the UnityResolver.cs class, below is the exception I am getting:

> System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'

Is there any idea about that?

My UnityConfig.cs

```
 public static class UnityConfig
    {
        public static UnityContainer Config()
        {
            UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

            container.RegisterType<IProduct, ProductBLL>();

            return container;
        }
    }
```

My WebApiConfig.cs

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var container = UnityConfig.Config();
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
        
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And My UnityResolver.cs

```
public class UnityResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        var child = _container.CreateChildContainer();
        return new UnityResolver(child);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And My PracticeController.cs

```
public class PracticeController : ApiController
{
    private IProduct objProduct;

    public PracticeController(IProduct product)
    {
        this.objProduct = product;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string TestPractice()
    {

        string val = objProduct.InsertData();

        Console.WriteLine(val);
        Console.ReadLine();

        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I would advocate continuing to make your own attempts at the problem. Put the error message into a search engine, someone may have had the same problem before.

Comment: @NadeemShaikh I've seen that happen when there is a circular dependency.

Comment: @Nkosi the code I have shared here is the only code using which I am trying to achieve, apart from this I don't have any extra code, which line of code you think is having circular dependency?

Comment: @halfer thanks, I am doing that only but still no luck.